# WordPress plugin for selling digital goods

Tags: wordpress, ecommerce

I am searching a WordPress plugin to add e-commerce ability to website. 
The website will have only digital goods - like WordPress plugins and themes.

Features I would like to have:

- licensing with easy managing of when license was expired

So far I found 2 options:

- [WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) (free) with [Software add-on](https://woocommerce.com/products/software-add-on/) (paid)
- [Easy Digital Downloads](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-digital-downloads/) (free) with [Licensing extension](https://easydigitaldownloads.com/downloads/software-licensing/) (paid)

Can you help me to choose among those options?

Or maybe you can provide third option I am not aware of?

Comment: Woo is the best. Yet another fine product of the Woo Tang Clan.

Answer (score 2):

Good choice - both are pretty solid. The reason why I'd cast my vote for Woo is the payment gateways. At the end of the day that is the only thing that matters.

You go out of your way to get the traffic in, finally people make up their minds to pay, and then... they bounce because... it no longer matters why - the payment gateway failed, and there goes a customer empty handed, feeling let down. I've been on both sides of this game, both seller and customer and out of a hundred factors, this would be my number one decisive variable.

Woo https://woocommerce.com/product-category/woocommerce-extensions/payment-gateways/ has an astounding number of providers supported. EDD seems more limited: http://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/861-payment-gateways